# inline conditionals in angular.js for add plural words

Tags: angularjs

I tried make a condition in angular, but i got a problem.

I want when the length be: 0 and 1 load this = product selected

and is != 1  load this = products selected.

I tried as bellow but I could not make, any help? thank you.

```
<h1 class="text-left" ng-show="section.selected_obj.length == 0 || == 1">{{product.title}} ({{product.selected_obj.length}}) product selected</h1>


<h1 class="text-left" ng-show="section.selected_obj.length != 1">{{product.title}} ({{product.selected_obj.length}}) products selected</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
<h1 class="text-left">{{product.title}} ({{product.selected_obj.length}}) product{{section.selected_obj.length > 1 ? 's' : ''}} selected</h1>
```